# Authorising Office365 logic app API Connection with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-logic-apps

Trying to setup a bunch of logic apps with supporting Azure functions etc. concept is to utilize ML/Azure functions/Logic apps etc. to setup an automated mailing system.

Everything is deployed using ADO/Git with CD/CI pipelines, but we have a problem with the Office365 connector that needs authorisation after creation. For now, we have followed this article that creates a [windows form for authentication](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ronba/2016/05/09/using-powershell-and-the-office-365-rest-api-with-oauth/).

This works fine, but we want to do this at scale and thus are looking for a silent approach, any ideas or links would be appreciated?

PS. Use does not require MFA

Comment: How you have added logic app step in CICD?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, the Office365 API authorisation works with the **OAuth 2.0 Authorisation Code Grant Type**, which means, you can only get the authorisation code by getting the user owning the mailbox (or having access to the shared mailbox) to sign in to get the code. This behaviour of the API is by design. Thus, there is no way to fully automate this.

If you don't need different accounts for different Logic Apps, you can create those API connections with PowerShell (still requiring the user to login in) for each environment and then use the already provisioned API in our CD pipeline.

Comment: Thx for reply, sendgrid is a bit over the top sadly. We will stick with manual authentication, its a one time task so should be durable :-)