# How do you Authenticate a Logic app microsoft.web/connections connection with code

Tags: azure, office365, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app with an Office 365 connection. Of course I can authenticate this in the portal *manually* but I would have to do this every time I deploy from my deployment automation pipeline.

I have found a post of this but it is no longer available:

[Authenticating office365 logic app connector with PS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186466/authenticating-office365-logic-app-connector-with-ps)

[The link that is no longer available](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ronba/2016/05/09/using-powershell-and-the-office-365-rest-api-with-oauth/)

Here is what I mean in the portal:
[image]

Any idea how I automate this with say Powershell or az clie or something else?

thanks
Russ

Answer (score 0):

***This question was answered by Microsoft:***

**Issue description:**

You are unable to change the user name for the Office 365 API connection

**Scope definition:**

To provide assistance on the above issue with Office 365 API connection

**Troubleshooting steps:**

I tried the repro of the scenario and tried the below options

1. Used incognito window- did not help
2. Tried creating a new API connection with the new user- did not help
3. Logged out of the office 365 suite- did not help
4. Logged in to the machine with the new account- it worked

**Resolution:**

Based on the observations, I had discussions with the experts, and it seems the connector currently can only take windows AD authentication and hence the issue.
Product group has this feature update in the backlog  and would be updating the connector in coming days, we do not have an ETA yet on this.

**Workaround option:**

1. Use portal from a server which doesn’t need domain user login. Login
   to the server with non-domain user
2. Use Mozilla Firefox browser- this
   has worked for few customers.